# Javascript XPATH issues

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have an XML object (y) that looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?> 
<message xmlns="jabber:client" type="groupchat">
    <body>https://[something].com/*.txt</body>
    <media xmlns="urn:xmpp:message:multimedia">
        <source src="https://[something].com/*.txt" type="text/plain" />
    </media>
    <html xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <a href="https://[something].com/*.txt">View Paste</a>
        </body>
    </html>
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
        <composing />
    </x>
    <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" />
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" />
</message>
```

Here is what I'm trying to use to get the "xmlns" attribute within `<media>` , but I'm not able to get it. 
Even when I do the following, I can't seem to get that one attribute within `<media>`.

```
var z = y.evaluate("//@*",y,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
z.iterateNext()
```

I want to be able to get somthing like this with z.iterateNext():

```
xmlns="urn:xmpp:message:multimedia"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath data model does not consider namespace declarations as attributes, so using XPath `@*` will not find any namespace declarations like `xmlns="http://example.com/foo"` or `xmlns:pf="http://example.com/bar"`. There are namespace nodes (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#namespace-nodes) in scope however you can select using the namespace axis (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) (if supported, I think Mozilla browsers using the Gecko engine do not support it, and somehow the snippet below does not find anything using the namespace axis in Chrome or Edge either).

```js
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<message xmlns="jabber:client" type="groupchat">
<body>https://[something].com/*.txt</body>
<media xmlns="urn:xmpp:message:multimedia">
    <source src="https://[something].com/*.txt" type="text/plain" />
</media>
<html xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <a href="https://[something].com/*.txt">View Paste</a>
    </body>
</html>
<x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
    <composing />
</x>
<delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" />
<x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" />
</message>`, 'application/xml');

var media = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'media')[0];


console.log('media.namespaceURI: ' + media.namespaceURI);

var xpathResult = xmlDoc.evaluate('namespace::*', media, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var ns = null;

while ((ns = xpathResult.iterateNext()) != null) {
  console.log('Found in-scope namespace "' + ns.namespaceURI + '" with prefix "' + ns.prefix + '"');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Big help! +1

Comment: Another Question, is it possible to directly check if <media> exists with one xmlDoc.evaluate statement?

Comment: I think using `var media = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'media')[0]`; if (media) ...` has better support than using XPath and `evaluate`,  if you want to use XPath and don't know the namespace then using `//*[local-name() = 'media']` as the path should do to select and then depending on the result type you request you can check `singleNodeValue` or the snapshot length or try to iterate.

Comment: @lolio312: If you consider this answer to be helpful, please click on this "really" nice arrow to accept it.